# How to update the cached files in my service worker every 30 minutes?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have this service worker:

```
//IMPORT POLYFILL
importScripts('cache-polyfill.js');

//INSTALL
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open('stock_item_balance_v1').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/app/offline_content/purchase/stock_items/stock_items_balance.php',
                '/app/offline_content/purchase/stock_items/js/stock_items_balance.js'
            ]);
        })
    );
});

//FETCH (FETCH IS WHEN YOU CHECK FOR INTERNET)
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.request.url); 

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
            
        })
    );
});
```

In "stock_items_balance.php" i fetch data from my DB. So in every 30 minutes i would like to update my cached pages and reload the window.

So first i have a script that checks for internet connection.
If true, i want to clean/update the cache and reload the page.

How can i do that?

```
//INTERVAL
setInterval(function(){
    
  //CLEAN/UPDATE CACHED FILES
  serviceworker.update(); // ???

  //RELOAD PAGE
  window.location.reload();

}, 180000);
```

Comment: @a.mola Yeah, but that isn't my problem or question. I've updated it tho.

Comment: You could try to append a parameter to the end of the files you’re trying to request for... like version number or the time stamp `file.php?v=1.0.1`

Comment: That’s how I ensure files I load into my website are recached after every serious upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I think you have a larger question as to whether the approach you describe is actually going to give a good, predictable, offline-capable experience for your users, but I'm just going to focus on the actual technical question you asked.)*

#### Messaging the service worker

First off, you should keep in mind that it's possible to have multiple tabs open for the same URL, and if you, you're going to end up with your update code potentially running multiple times. The code in this answer handles the "reload" step for you from inside of the service worker, after the asynchronous cache update has completed, by getting a list of all the active clients of the service worker and telling each to navigate to the current URL (which is effectively a reload).

```
// Additions to your service worker code:
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // Optional: if you need to potentially send different
  // messages, use a different identifier for each.
  if (event.data === 'update') {
    event.waitUntil((async () => {
      // TODO: Move these URLs and cache names into constants.
      const cache = await caches.open('stock_item_balance_v1');
      await cache.addAll([
        '/app/offline_content/purchase/stock_items/stock_items_balance.php',
        '/app/offline_content/purchase/stock_items/js/stock_items_balance.js'
      ]);
      const windowClients = await clients.matchAll();
      for (const windowClient of windowClients) {
        // Optional: check windowClient.url first and
        // only call navigate() if it's the URL for one
        // specific page.
        windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url);
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

```
// Additions to your window/page code:
setInterval(() => {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('update');
  }
}, 180000);
```

#### What won't work

The Cache Storage API is available from both inside a service worker and inside of your page's `window` scope. Normally what I'd recommend that folks do is to open up the same cache from the `window` context, and call `cache.add()` to update the cached entry with the latest from the network. However, calling `cache.add()` from the `window` context **will** cause the network request to be intercepted by your `fetch` handler, and at that point, your response won't actually come from the network. By calling `cache.add()` from inside your service worker, you can [guarantee](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#:%7E:text=If%20r%E2%80%99s%20client%27s%20global%20object%20is%20a%20ServiceWorkerGlobalScope%20object%2C%20set%20request%E2%80%99s%20service-workers%20mode%20to%20%22none%22.) that the resulting network request won't trigger your `fetch` handler.

Comment: I added this code to my service worker. But the page never reloads. And if i reload it manually it's still an old cached version. In the main php file: stock_items_balance.php i i echo a datetime.. to check if its a new version the time is suposed to be updated.. but it isn't.. ?!